# PHP Error messages work, but file uploads still go through

Tags: php

I've written a blogging application that uploads an image file and saves the file name to a database. I've included checks to prevent uploads of files larger than 500KB and files that are not jpg, png, webp or gif files.

If oversized or invalid image types are detected, the user is redirected to the posting form with an error message. The issue I've encountered is that the detection process works, but the invalid image files are uploaded anyway.

As I'm just learning PHP, I can't figure out what I've missed. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Post Form - makepost.php

```
<!-- HEADER.PHP -->
<?php require "templates/header.php" ?>
  <main class="container p-4 bg-light mt-3" style="width: 1000px">
    <!-- createpost.inc.php - Will process the data from this form-->
    <form action="includes/makepost.inc.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h2>Create Post</h2>

      <!-- Error Message -->
      <?php
        // VALIDATION: Check that Error Message Type exists in GET superglobal
        if(isset($_GET['error'])){
          // (1) Empty fields validation 
          if($_GET['error'] == "emptyfields"){
            $errorMsg = "Please fill in all fields";

          // (2) Internal server error 
          } else if ($_GET['error'] == "sqlerror") {
            $errorMsg = "An internal server error has occurred - please try again later";

          // (3) Banner Image file name already exists 
          } else if ($_GET['error'] == "file-name-match") {
            $errorMsg = "Sorry, this banner image file already exists. Please rename your file.";

          // (4) Banner Image file size is to large 
          } else if ($_GET['error'] == "file-size-to-large") {
            $errorMsg = "Sorry, your banner image file is too large. Please reduce our image file size.";

          // (5) Is the uploaded image using a valid file type
          } else if ($_GET['error'] == "invalid-file-type") {
            $errorMsg = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF & WEBP files are allowed.";

          // (6) Is the upload an actual image file
          } else if ($_GET['error'] == "file-is-not-an-image-file") {
            $errorMsg = "Sorry, your file is not an image.";

          } else if ($_GET['error'] == "unknown-or-general-error") {
            $errorMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
          }
          
          // (8) Dynamic Error Alert based on Variable Value 
          echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' . $errorMsg . '</div>';

        }
      ?>
      <!-- 1. Article Titile -->
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="">
      </div>  

      <!-- 2. Upload Image File -->
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="fileToUpload" class="form-label">Banner Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="fileToUpload">
      </div>

      <!-- 3. Article Extract -->
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="extract" class="form-label">Article Extract</label>
        <textarea id="extract-textarea" class="form-control" name="extract" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>

      <!-- 3. Article Text -->
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="article" class="form-label">Article Text</label>
        <textarea id="article-textarea" class="form-control" name="article" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>

      <!-- 4. Submit Button -->
      <button type="submit" name="post-submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Post</button>
    </form>
  </main>
<!-- FOOTER.PHP -->
<?php require "templates/footer.php" ?>
```

The includes file the process the post - makepost.inc.php

```
<?php
  // 01) Start Session.
  session_start();

  // 02) Load the upload directory config.
  require 'config.inc.php';

  // 03) Set the upload parameters.
  $target_file = $directory . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // 04) Check user clicked submit button from makepost form + user is logged in.
  if(isset($_POST['post-submit']) && isset($_SESSION['userId']) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
    
    // 05) Load the database connection settings file.
    require 'connect.inc.php';

    // 06) Collect andstore POST data
    $title = $_POST['title']; // Post Title.
    $imageURL = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']; // Image URL - Add option for image upload.
    $extract  = $_POST['extract']; // Post Extract.
    $article  = $_POST['article']; // Article Text.
    $postdate  = date("Y-m-d"); // Get Current Date for Post Date.
    $author  = $_SESSION['userUid']; // Use 'userUid' in $_SESSION Varible for Author Name.

    // 07) VALIDATION: Check if any fields are empty.
    if (empty($title ) || empty($imageURL) || empty($extract) || empty($article) || empty($postdate) || empty($author)) {
    
      // 08) ERROR: Redirect + error via GET.
      header("Location: ../makepost.php?error=emptyfields");
      exit();

      // 09) Checks if the image files size exceeds file size limit of 500KB.
      } else if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
      header("Location: ../makepost.php?error=file-size-to-large"); 
      $uploadOk = 0;
      exit();

      // 10) Checks if the image is a an excepted file type.     
      } else if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
      && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "webp" ) {
      header("Location: ../makepost.php?error=invalid-file-type");
      $uploadOk = 0;
      exit();

    // 11) Save the post to the database using prepared statements.
    } else {
      // 12) Declare Template SQL with ? Placeholders to save values to table.
      $sql = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

      // 13) Init SQL statement.
      $statement = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

      // 14) Prepare + send statement to database to check for errors.
      if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($statement, $sql))
      {
        // 15) ERROR: Something wrong when preparing the SQL.
        header("Location: ../makepost.php?error=sqlerror"); 
        exit();
      } else {
        // 16) SUCCESS: Bind our user data with statement + escape strings.
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssss", $title, $imageURL, $extract,  $article, $postdate, $author);

        // 17) Execute the SQL Statement with user data.
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        // 18) SUCCESS: Post is saved to "posts" table - redirect with success message.
        header("Location: ../index.php?post=success"); 
        exit();
      }
    }
  // 19) Restrict Access to Script Page.
  } else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
  }
?>
```

I've tryed adding exit(); to the end of the else if statements but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: Your first "if" statement code is executing always that's why files get uploaded. 
Check file size and extension type before the if statement.
I hope you will get the idea

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` happens before you check for any kind of errors. It makes no sense to try and copy the file to its final destination _before_ you've validated it.

Comment: Would you recommend moving move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) to the else statement where the data is saved to the database?

Comment: That would make a lot more sense  yes

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that you do the `move_uploaded_file` before you check the filesize and so on. You are doing it in the if statement. That means as soon `$_POST['post-submit']` and `$_SESSION['userId']` exists, you already try to save the file.

You need to check everything first and in case nothing is wrong, you do the `move_uploaded_file`. You need to move it to the else where you save the stuff in the database.

Thats already the main answer.

What I would reccomend, is change the way you think a bit. Specially on fileuploads it might be important. At the moment the code works like "everything is fine as long nothing is wrong and when something is wrong it can be this or this or this."

I would change it to "nothing is right, as long there is no proove".

When doing it clever, it can be also with a better overview. and you dont need a bunch of elseif.

Here an example of the different way i mean. (it is not a fully working code, it is just to show the way.)

```
<?php
// here you list all the checks you need to do and set al of them to false. 
// this gives an overview that you need to check.
$checks = [
    'emptyValues'     => false,
    'fileSize'        => false,
    'imageDimensions' => false,
    'imageMimeTypes'  => false,
    'imageType'       => false,
];

// then you do the checks. and set each one on true, when they pass.
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 500000) {
    $checks['filesize' = true];
}

// when checking the filetype it is not enough to just check the extension. 
// because, someone who is evil could just upload 
// for example a javascript with a jpg as extension. 
// at the moment it would pass all the checks. 
// so when just pictures are allowed you could add a check for [getimagesize][1]. 
// that has the effect, that everything that is not an image cannot pass, 
// even when the extension got changed to jpg.

$size = getimagesize($filename);
if($size[0] > 1 && $size[0] < 2048 && $size[1] > 1 && $size[1] < 2048) {
    $checks['imageDimensions'] = true;
}

$allowedMimetypes = ['image/png ', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif'];

// on images we can reuse the result of getimagesize. 
// In case something else apart from pictures is allowed, 
// we can't do the check for the width and height. 
// there we would need to use `mime_content_type`
if(in_array($size['mime'])) {
    $checks['imageMimeTypes'] = true;
}

// then before you save something, search if there are still some values on false.
$error = array_search(false, $checks, true);

// just in case there is nothing left $error will be false. 
// in every other case it will be the first key of the array
// where the check didn't succeed. 
// Here you need to do a strict check, because it is just real boolean false, 
// in case nothing got found. in case you would use a numeric array, 
// it would deliver false in case check where the key is 0 failed.
if($error === false) {
    // here you save the file and write to database.
} else {
    // when it ends up here, then something went wrong.
    // it could be that a check failed, 
    // or that you forgot to do a check, that is listet as todo in your array.
    // because keys of arrays are strings or integer, 
    // you can do just one header location call, 
    // that delivers the key of the first error.
    header("Location: ../makepost.php?error=".$checkResult);
    exit;
}
```

Apart from that, it might be good, to seperate some things to functions.
For example one function for the checks, one for creating the connection, one for the querys, one for moving the uploaded file
and so on.
In case what they do was successfull, they return true, if not false. (otherwise you could also make them throw an exception when something is wrong, but true or false for the beginning is easier).
Then first you would define all the functions and then you do just call them and check if the previous one was successfull.
The benefit would be that you sepparate all the different things you do, what gives a nice overview and you are able to reuse parts in other places. So for example when you create another fileupload in another place of your site, you could use the same function for checking, instead of write the same again.